# Get Wordpress options in outside PHP file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using some custom scripting to recall saved theme options from the Wordpress database.

`<?php $options = get_option('theme_options'); ?>`

My question is, I can only use this inside Wordpress them files like `header.php` or `page.php`, but **how can I call these options outside of the standard theme files**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access WP functions you need to call `wp-load.php`:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( '../path/to/wp-load.php' );
$options = get_option( 'theme_options' );
```

Comment: It's not recommended to load wp-load.php: http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/

Comment: It depends. If you're using this in a WP plugin you're definitely on the wrong track. Legitimate use would be to gain access to WP functions, classes and data from an external, custom PHP app for example. As to retrieving data the WP API will be the way the go, once it has been merged in core.